# Fast-Play 1 Hr. Video (with Audio stream) in 2 min

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

For a Research Project in brain and cognition we need to show the subjects  1Hr. videos in 2 mins. I understand there is a function in most media players out there to speed up the video.
But I'm not sure if the function does this by actually showing the videos at higher FPS or just by dropping some frames. I need to make sure we show *all* the frames that are there.
The same is the issue with the audio stream.

Is there some way to make sure we show the subject *all* the frames and all the *bits* of the audio stream- just way too fast?

Answer (score 2):

Yes many video players would begin to drop frames as soon as it got to like 4X speed. 
Your specs are to get a video to play at 30 times normal speed, and not drop frames.  That would be easy to do if the original video is 2FPS (frame per second) playback rate :-)

The general high frame rate for computers is 60FPS , so a 24-30FPS would easily be able to be sped up to 2X.  With the correct combination of hardware and a 120htz refresh rate monitor, you could then potentially get to 4X speed.  If your original video had the frame rate of 24FPS You could manage to get to 5X.
The problem with the above already is , many LCD monitors claiming a 120Htz refresh rate, as tested in labs and the info shown on the web, do not really even keep up with the 120 itself. The miliseconds needed to fully change the picture were higher than the frame rate you could pump to the monitor, so it is smooth by 120Fps, but not actually the same as, as some pixels will not actually fully change yet.  (not quite lying, but not fully doing what you would expect).  So far we are at only 5X speed, and it would not be a good "Control" without knowing for fact that the information was displayed the same.

The Max claims are about 240htz refresh rates, My research shows while the internal engine of some of these, was capable of 240, and this was used to 'improve the picture" the pannels themselves couldnt actually do it, based on thier own specs looking at the fine print.  Assuming it could , or you could make people believe it did, were up to 10X , and there is a long way to go :-)

BlurBusters Is a nice place to read about refresh rates  http://www.blurbusters.com/faq/lcd-motion-artifacts/ And has listings for "true" and more true high refresh rate computer monitors.

The above is about the time it takes to change the usual LCD light valve, or even push some of the fastest LCD light valves, but not all monitors have LCD light valves.

The LED (not led backlight) or OLED or AMOLED monitors use led, led (non-phosphor) itself is capable of turning on and off in a milisecond. Finnaly we are to where it would be possible to change what the user sees fast enough.  Now we just have to add to that a display engine running the LED screen at a very high rate.  They will do a real 120, and some high end models a real 240htz refresh rate.  (also plasma could)

It is going to take lots of bandwidth for data, because data for monitors is an uncompressed signal, the bandwidth would have to be 30 times to display the data at 30 times as fast.  They do not even make a LED monitor that works in that way for the general consumer.
 Because total bandwidth would be highly dependant on screen resolution, the machines trying to do 30X framerate would probably do so at a lower resolution.
(need citation for dvi or hdmi max data transfer rates)

Try and find first a monitor that has both an engine and a display system that actually changes the total frame the same way at 720FPS. It is likely that any monitor that actually can display much faster and fully changes the picture would do so using Leds or plasma, not lcd light valves. That discludes LED backlight LCD pannels.

Some previous studies of this type used Film, the shutter for film can block and unblocks light faster than LCD and fully,  You might be able to find a film projector that plays film back at high speeds, and can also be cranked up to even higher speeds. over 500? I think the film would come flying out of the sprockets :-)

This document is subject to correction, if anybody has any better ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.I'd not even thought the problem with very high fps would be deeper than being just in software. Just out of curiosity I did an internet search for very high refresh-rate monitors/tvs. The highest I've found (so far) is 1000Hz. But since you've informed regarding the reality of 120Hz monitors, one could just wonder if the 1000Hz refresh-rate is real. Apparently, cinematograph is not an answer at such high fps, as you've already noted. You seem to have a deep knowledge in this area, so please be kind enough to share any idea as to how it could be done.

Comment: I do not have deep knowlege, I just would like to see better video frame rates, and some specs were changing without the technology changing, so something was wrong. Like the milisecond specs started using G-G (grey to grey) Instead of full on/off. They were still doing many visual tricks to fool the human eye.  The info above is by no means complete, but that is about all I can cover.  Did you check out the blurbusters link, and the monitor info they have there?

Comment: There are also many many ways to capture a frame, or frame rate at very high-speeds, but even those deep into high-speed cameras, did not cover any very high-speed displaying. All that technology and effort is about slowing things down, stopping motion for analisis. There is a lot of belief that humans are incapable of seeing at high rates, because they "percieve motion" when there is like more than 18FPS, which has nothing to do with how quickly the human eye and brain could process information. One Study shows Jet pilots could see a 1/250th sec. picture change.